# Node execPath references VSCode installation instead of path to Node installation

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have a NodeJS process that is used in a shared library that does the following:

```
async function execNpmInstall(currWorkingDirectory: string) {
  const exec = promisify(childProcess.exec);
  return await exec(`${process.execPath} npm install`, {
    cwd: currWorkingDirectory,
  });
}
```

The problem is, when I call `execNpmInstall`, the process.execPath is replaced with the path of my VSCode extension, whereas I want it to be set to the location of where ndoe is installed. I found through the documentation (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference):

${execPath} - the path to the running VS Code executable

When I execute the code, I get the following error:

```
Error: Command failed: /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Frameworks/Code Helper (Plugin).app/Contents/MacOS/Code Helper (Plugin) npm install 
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: `/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Frameworks/Code Helper (Plugin).app/Contents/MacOS/Code Helper (Plugin) node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js install --ignore-scripts'
```

I tried to see if there was any way to find if there was any way to get the executable that started the Node.js process outside of process.execPath but I can't find any way to reference the node executable in any other way. Is there any way for me to resolve the process.execPath to be the "node" process.execPath and not the VS Code extension execPath variable?